# Flexible array subsetting

Tags: arrays, r

I would like to write a function that takes as an input an array X with a variable number of dimensions (e.g., `dim(X) => c(2,3)`, or `dim(X) => c(2,3,5)`), and a list of dimension indices and a numeric index. The function return the subset of the array, based on the dimension and indices specified. For example:

```
dim(B) => c(2,5,10)
FUN(B, list(list(2,1:3), list(3,6:10))) => B[, 1:3, 6:10]
```

the challenge comes from the fact that the dimensions of B are not specified in advance. The best solution I can come up with is generate a string  `s <- "B[,1:3, 6:10]"` (details omitted and unimportant) and then issue an eval(parse(text=s)). I don't think this is an elegant solution, and probably not an efficient one either. I wonder if someone can come up with a simple approach.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. I think you mean something demonstrated by the following: if I have `array(1:27, c(3, 3, 3))`, then supplying it and a vector `c(2,2,2)` should give me the the corresponding item (in this case 14), but for an arbitrary number of dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **[similar to this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22520752/assign-values-to-a-specific-dimension-of-array-in-r/22521832#22521832)**.  The general strategy is to produce a list of indices for all dimensions, where non specified dimensions are represented by a single `TRUE`, which then allows you to call `[` with `do.call`:

```
sub_arr <- function(X, lst) {
  dim.list <- as.list(rep(T, length(dim(X))))
  dim.list[vapply(lst, `[[`, 1, 1)] <- lapply(lst, `[[`, 2)
  do.call(`[`, c(list(X), dim.list))
}
B <- array(1:16, dim=rep(2, 4))
sub_arr(B, list(list(2, 1:2), list(3, 1)))
```

Produces:

```
, , 1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
, , 2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    9   11
[2,]   10   12
```

And:

```
identical(
  B[, 1:2, 1, ],
  sub_arr(B, list(list(2, 1:2), list(3, 1)))
)
# [1] TRUE
```